# Direction of spacetime curvature?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, forces, spacetime, curvature

I am honestly new to all. But, I am confused about space time curvature and gravity.
I see in lots of graphs that the spacetime bends when there is a mass in it, and that bend is in the direction of downwards. Electromagnetic force push everything on it to the centre because it curves.
However, earth is a globe and a downward position and the direction of the curve of spacetime are relative to where you are on that globe, not like on those graphs. It is in the all direction of the globe.
In such condition, what would be the electromagnetic force, is it like coming in one direction and neutralize with the other coming from opposite direction?  can we say the direction of the curve is to the centre, in all directions? If so, why we are pulled or pushed to the centre?

Comment: Those "rubber sheet" pictures depict the curvature of a two dimensional manifold. When we talk about spacetime, we are talking about curvature of a _four_ dimensional manifold, which is practically impossible to visualize. Also, spacetime is not space. Consider a gun with a laser sight: The laser photons and the bullet both follow nearly the same path through space from the gun to the target, but the [_world lines_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_line) through spacetime that represent the _motion_ of the bullet and the motion of a photon are very different from each other.

Answer (score 1):

> I see in lots of graphs that the spacetime bends when there is a mass in it, and that bend is in the direction of downwards

You can pretty much ignore all of those illustrations.

What the idea that spacetime is curved means is that near a large mass geometry is not Euclidean. If you connect three locally straight lines you will find that the angles don't add up to 180 degrees. More importantly, free-falling objects are not acted on by any force, so free-falling objects travel in locally straight lines and because spacetime is curved such straight lines can intersect multiple times.

The illustrations just don't capture such things.